# Buscar todos os registos de um respectivo ano e mês

Tags: php, mysql

Na minha BD tenho o campo data do tipo date (YYYY-mm-dd). O que acontece é que quero ir buscar todos os registos de um determinado ano e mês. Por exemplo, quero ir buscar todos os registos de 2014 do mês 08. Como posso fazer isso? tentei algo do género:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_ocorrencias WHERE `data` = '2014-08-d'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_ocorrencias
WHERE
   YEAR( data ) = 2014 AND MONTH( data ) = 8
```